# Взять из текста только url

Tags: php

У нас есть произвольный текст:

```
Line: 100 http://hashcode.ru/
Line: 1 http://hashcode.ru/privet
```

Как оставить только url?
Наработки:

```
$url_list = file_get_contents('url.txt');
$url_explode = explode('http://',$url_list);
$count = count($url_explode);
$i = 0;
while($count>$i) {
echo "http://".$url_explode[$i]."<br>";
$i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как изъять отсюда: "Line: 100 http://hashcode.ru/" адрес?
Вот так:

```
$str="Line: 100 http://hashcode.ru";
$str2=strstr(strtolower($str),'http://');
echo($str2); // display
```

**Тогда так:**

> ```
> $str="Line: 100 http://hashcode.ru Line: 100 http://hashcode.ru";
> $offset=0;
> $pos_space=1;
> while($pos_space)
> {
>   $pos_http = stripos($str,'http://',$offset);
>   if(!$pos_http) break;
>   $pos_space = strpos($str,' ',$pos_http);
>   if(!$pos_space) $pos_space=strlen($str)-1;
>   $offset=$pos_space+1;
>   $newstr=substr($str,$pos_http,trim($pos_space-$pos_http+1));
>   echo($newstr."<br>");
>   }
> ```

Comment: Переделал под много строк:

[code]
$url_list = file_get_contents('url.txt');
$url_explode = explode('\n\r',$url_list);
$count = count($url_explode);
$i = 0;
while($count>$i) {
$url_explode[$i] = trim($url_explode[$i]);
$nnn = strstr(strtolower($url_explode[$i]),'http://');
echo $nnn."<br>";
$i++;
}[code]

Если адресов несколько, то получается вот так:

[code]http://hashcode.ru/ 1 
http://hashcode.ru/privet[/code]

Или так:

[code]http://hashcode.ru/
line: 1 http://hashcode.ru/privet[/code]

Answer (score 1):

```
$links = array();
foreach (explode("\n", $text) as $line)
  $links[] = 'http://'.trim(end(explode('http://', $line)));
print_r($links);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$s = 'Line: 100 http://hashcode.ru/
Line: 1 http://hashcode.ru/privet';

preg_match_all('~(https?://[\w\./\?\-]+)~', $s, $m);
print_r($m);
```